# Get item from template in ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, xaml

I have an ItemsControl that is populated with an observable collection of some ViewModel classes, like so:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate Type="{x:Type local:MyViewModel}">
      <Button Content="{Binding ActionName}" Click="ClickHandler"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Works great, looks great, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the "ClickHandler" to be aware of the class 'MyViewModel' that is represented by the data template.  Behold!

```
private void ClickHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  // The 'sender' is the button that raised the event.  Great!
  // Now how do I figure out the class (MyViewModel) instance that goes with this button?
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your own answer will do the trick in this specific case. Here's another technique which, while much more complicated, will also work on any scenario regardless of complexity:

Starting from `sender` (which is a `Button`), use [`VisualTreeHelper.GetParent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.getparent.aspx) until you find a `ContentPresenter`. This is the type of `UIElement` that the `ItemTemplate` you specified is hosted into for each of your items. Let's put that `ContentPresenter` into the variable `cp`. (*Important: if your `ItemsControl` were a `ListBox`, then instead of `ContentPresenter` we 'd look for a `ListBoxItem`, etc*).

Then, call [`ItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(cp)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.itemfromcontainer.aspx). To do that, you will need to have some reference to the specific `ItemsControl` but this shouldn't be hard -- you can, for example, give it a `Name` and use [`FrameworkElement.FindName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname.aspx) from your View itself. The `ItemFromContainer` method will return your ViewModel.

All of this I learned from the stupidly useful and eye-opening posts of [Dr.](http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/03/25/itemscontrol-i-is-for-item-container/) [WPF](http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/07/20/itemscontrol-g-is-for-generator/).

Comment: Ah very good.  This will obviously work much better than the approach that I listed, but only for a very complex template with non-default data contexts.

Comment: This is probably silly, but could you combine my answer with yours?  They are both 'correct' in some sense, and I'd like to give you the green check since your is more complete.  I think others could benefit from both approaches depending on what they are doing.

Comment: @A.R.: No need for that. I edited it a bit to explicitly refer to your own answer. I think it's very much in the spirit of SO for multiple useful answers to be present.

Answer (score 9):

OK duh, I almost immediately realized that it is the 'DataContext' of the 'sender'.  I am going to leave this up unless the community thinks that this question is just too obvious.

```
private void ClickHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  // This is the item that you want.  Many assumptions about the types are made, but that is OK.
  MyViewModel model = ((sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as MyViewModel);
}
```

Comment: This is far better, easier and applies to other similar situations, too, than the accepted answer.