# How to attach OnClick event to a WPF button inside ListBox's <DataTemplate> from codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to find a way to attach an event (OnClick) to a button that is a part of a ListBox, inside the ListItem and DataTemplate elements. This is being done from a C# scripting space inside another application which doesn't accept event binding from XAML code but does allow me to do runtime binding. For other controls, which are not inside a data template like the lstSaveSetups ListBox, I use the LogicalTreeHelper, find the element I need and then just bind it. That doesn't work here, and I have also unsuccessfully tried FindName as well as many other approaches.

This is the XAML:

```
  <ListBox Name="lstSavedSetups" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="25" />
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding 1stColumn}" />
          <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding 2ndColumn}" />
          <Button Grid.Column="2" Name="btnDelete" />
        </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
```

The simplilfied c# code is:

```
System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(System.IO.Path.Combine(myBaseDir, @"listBox.xaml"), System.IO.FileMode.Open);
System.Windows.Controls.Page page = (System.Windows.Controls.Page)System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(fs);

lstSavedSetups = LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode(page, "lstSavedSetups") as System.Windows.Controls.ListBox;

System.Windows.Controls.Grid.SetRow(lstSavedSetups, 16);
System.Windows.Controls.Grid.SetColumn(lstSavedSetups, 1);

myGrid.Children.Add(lstSavedSetups);
//the following works
lstSavedSetups.SelectionChanged += lstSavedSetups_SelectionChanged;

//one of many examples of what does not work:
System.Windows.Controls.Button btnDelete = lstSavedSetups.ItemTemplate.FindName("btnDelete", lstSavedSetups) as System.Windows.Controls.Button;

btnDelete.Click += btnDelete_OnClick;
```

I didn't include all that I tried, but I am starting to think I tried every single solution I could find but didn't manage to get this to work.

What am I doing wrong? Any help will be really appreciated! Thank you!

Libor

Comment: look for "wpf event databinding"

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5400511/1384679) about `ItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer`

Comment: Add the property `ClickMode="Press"` to your Button to get the event instead of it getting hijacked by listboxitem.

Comment: I think that even for Page you load from code, you need to call its InitializeComponenets() method, no?